Confidence interval for entropy from Basharin’s asymptotic normality result
Setup:
Say we have i.i.d. observations $X_1, \dots, X_N$ from the distribution given by
$$
0 < p_i := \mathbb P(X_j = i) < 1, \quad i = 1, \dots, s, \quad \text{and} \quad \sum_{i = 1}^s p_i = 1. 
$$
We are estimating the distribution’s entropy $H := -\sum_{i= 1}^s p_i \log_2 p_i$ using the maximum likelihood estimator:
$$
\hat H_N := \sum_{i=1}^s \hat p_i \log_2 \hat p_i,
$$
where $\hat p_i = \frac 1N \sum_{j = 1}^N \mathbf 1\{X_j = i\}$ for $i = 1, \dots, s$, i.e. the observed proportion $i$’s.
Question:
Basharin (1959) writes that we can use the following results to build confidence intervals:

$\sqrt N (\hat H_N - H)$ is asymptotically normal
$\mathbb E[\hat H_N] = H - \frac{s-1}{2N} \log_2(\text e) + O(1/N^{2})$
$\operatorname{Var}[\hat H_N] = \frac 1N \left[\big( \sum_{i=1}^s p_i(\log_2 p_i)^2\big) - H^2 \right] + O(1/N^2) =: \frac 1N \left[\eta - H^2 \right] + O(1/N^2)$.

How should we calculate such confidence intervals? I see two options (presented below). Which is better?
Both options use the fact that
$$
\sqrt \frac{N}{\eta - H^2} (\hat H_N - H) \overset{\mathcal D}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1),
$$
where $\eta := \sum_{i=1}^s p_i (\log_2 p_i)^2$, either:

Option 1
The SLLN, continuous mapping theorem, and Slutsky’s theorem yield
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt \frac{N}{\hat \eta_N - \hat H_N^2} (\hat H_N - H)
&= \underbrace{
\sqrt \frac{\eta - H^2}{\hat \eta_N - \hat H_N^2}
}_{\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}1} 
\underbrace{
\sqrt \frac{N}{\eta - H^2} (\hat H_N - H)
}_{\overset{\mathcal D}{\longrightarrow}N(0,1)}
\overset{\mathcal D}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1),
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\hat \eta_N := \sum_{i=1}^s \hat p_i (\log_2 \hat p_i)^2$. Then using a standard argument we get the asymptotic confidence interval
$$
\left[ 
\hat H_N - z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{N}{\hat \eta_N - \hat H_N}}, \quad \hat H_N + z_{1-\alpha/2}\sqrt{\frac{N}{\hat \eta_N - \hat H_N}}
\,\right].
$$

Option 2
Alternatively the SLLN, continuous mapping theorem, and Slutsky’s theorem also yield
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sqrt \frac{N}{\hat \eta_N - H^2} (\hat H_N - H)
&= \underbrace{
\sqrt \frac{\eta - H^2}{\hat \eta_N - H^2}
}_{\overset{\text{a.s.}}{\longrightarrow}1} 
\underbrace{
\sqrt \frac{N}{\eta - H^2} (\hat H_N - H)
}_{\overset{\mathcal D}{\longrightarrow}N(0,1)}
\overset{\mathcal D}{\longrightarrow} N(0,1).
\end{aligned}
$$
We can generate an asymptotic confidence interval as follows:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb P\left( z_{\alpha/2} \leq \sqrt \frac{N}{\hat\eta_N - H^2} (\hat H_N - H) \leq z_{1-\alpha/2} \right) \\
&= \mathbb P\left( - z_{1-\alpha/2} \leq \sqrt \frac{N}{\hat\eta_N - H^2} (\hat H_N - H) \leq z_{1-\alpha/2} \right)  \\
&= \mathbb P\left( |\hat H_N - H| \leq z_{1-\alpha/2} \sqrt \frac{\hat\eta_N - H^2}{N} \right) \\
&= \mathbb P\left( (\hat H_N - H)^2 \leq z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \cdot \frac{\hat\eta_N - H^2}{N} \right) \\
&= \mathbb P\left( \hat H_N^2 - 2 \hat H_N H + H^2 \leq \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N}H^2 \right) \\
&= \mathbb P\left( \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) H^2 + (- 2 \hat H_N) H + \Big( \hat H_N^2 - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) \leq 0 \right). \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Since we have an upward-facing quadratic in $H$, we can use the quadratic formula:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) H^2 + (- 2 \hat H_N) H + \Big( \hat H_N^2 - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) = 0 \\
\iff H &= \frac{-(- 2 \hat H_N) \pm \sqrt{(- 2 \hat H_N)^2 - 4\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\Big( \hat H_N^2 - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big)}}{2\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)} \\
&= \frac{\hat H_N \pm \sqrt{\hat H_N^2 - \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\Big( \hat H_N^2 - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big)}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)} \\
&= \frac{\hat H_N \pm \sqrt{ \Big(1 - 1 - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2 - \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( - \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big)}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)} \\
&= \frac{\hat H_N \pm \sqrt{ \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) -\Big(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)}
\end{aligned}
$$
Thus,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\mathbb P
\left(
\frac{\hat H_N - \sqrt{ \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) -\Big(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)}
\leq H \leq 
\frac{\hat H_N + \sqrt{ \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) -\Big(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)}
\right) \\
&= \mathbb P\left( z_{\alpha/2} \leq \sqrt \frac{N}{\hat\eta_N - H^2} (\hat H_N - H) \leq z_{1-\alpha/2} \right) \to 1-\alpha
\end{aligned}
$$
so we have the asymptotic confidence interval
$$
\left[
\frac{\hat H_N - \sqrt{ \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) -\Big(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)},
\quad
\frac{\hat H_N + \sqrt{ \Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big) \Big( \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2 \hat\eta_N}{N} \Big) -\Big(\frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)\hat H_N^2}}{\Big(1 + \frac{z_{1-\alpha/2}^2}{N} \Big)}
\right].
$$



Thoughts
Intuitively, Option 2 seems better to me, since we only have to “substitute” $\hat \eta_N - H^2$ for the asymptotic variance instead of $\hat\eta_N - \hat H_N^2$.
